# url-loader without webpack?

Tags: babeljs, urlloader

I have a component library that will be shipping with a few small assets (images).  Those assets are imported into various components in the library.

The build script uses babel (without webpack) to transpile the js(x) to a build directory, and is currently dumping the images into build/assets/images.

This works when testing the build, but when using the component in another project (using webpack) the component tries to refer the node_modules folder:

Example component:

```
import myImage from './assets/images/myImage.png';

const MyComponent = () => (
    <img src={myImage} />
);

export MyComponent;
```

Usage:

```
import MyComponent from 'myLibrary/MyComponent';

export default () => (
    <MyComponent />
);
```

The error message:

*myImage.png:1 GET http://localhost:9001/**node_modules/myLibrary/assets/images**/myImage.png 404 (Not Found)*

As I understand the 'best' way to include assets is to use the url-loader so they're converted to data uri's.  However, trying to use the url-loader without Webpack isn't working:

babel.config.js

```
    ...
    plugins: [
        [
            "url-loader",
            {
                "extensions": ["png", "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "svg", "pdf"],
                "limit": 0
            }
        ]
    ]
    ...
```

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-plugin-url-loader'

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it works for PNG and SVG files - worked perfectly for what I needed!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-inline-import-data-uri